# Sql server Agent job is failing with a login error

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2008 in SSMS
I'm getting this error when running a job I just created using SQL Server Agent:
Executed as user: DNA\circsrv. Database 'DN' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. [SQLSTATE 08004] (Error 911).  The step failed.

DNA is the name of a network domain, and circsrv is a valid user in that domain.

The Process for the Sql Server Agent is started by user DNA\circsrv but the job itself is owned by a different user, dn-atcore1\syncronexadmin
   @owner_login_name=N'DN-ATCORE1\syncronexadmin'
(dn-atcore1 is the name of the system, and syncronexadmin is a local user on the box)
This seems like it should be simple, but I'm just not getting it.
Any ideas? Thanks for any help.
Barb

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a database called 'DN'?  The error states that the database does not exist.  When you created the job did you set the database?

Comment: No, there is no database DN nor anything that starts with DN.  It's almost like it's starting to parse the DNA and just grabs the first 2 characters.

Comment: Here is my t-sql.  seems ok to me?                               exec sp_msforeachdb 'IF ''?''  in ("nsdb_DNA","nsdb_NICHE","NSSESSION")
BEGIN 
IF (SELECT state_desc FROM msdb.sys.databases WHERE [name] = ''?'') = ''ONLINE''
 BEGIN 
  use ?  execute dbasys.dbo.Maint_Index_Fragmentation_Check ''?''
 END

END'

Comment: this is not associaed with the sql job agent, as i first thought.  if i execute this EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'IF ''?'' = ''master''
BEGIN
USE ? PRINT DB_NAME()
END'                I will get the same error, e.g., Database 'DN' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Does the database exist?

Run this code to check.

```
-- main database
use master;
go

-- does the db exist?
select * 
from sys.sysdatabases
where name like 'DN%'
go
```

If it does not exist, you have bigger issues here!

Time to find a backup to restore from ...

Comment: SonOfA......  it's some kind of replication server.  That's why it does not show up my list of databases.  At least I know how to work around it now.  Thanks!!!